# Multiple p:dialog

Tags: primefaces

I use PrimeFaces 6. Now I have a page where I have a `p:dataTable` and I want to have multiple `p:dialog`s based on an action:

1. Add Dialog
2. Edit Dialog
3. Further Information Dialog

Using `p:dialog` I have to include them all into my main page. Which will blow up the page's content. Also the business logic resides in the main page's bean.

Is there any workaround?
I would like to have a structure like this

1. `dialogAdd.xhtml` and `dialogAdd.java`
2. `dialogEdit.xhtml` and `dialogEdit.java`
3. `dialogFurther.xhtml` and `dialogFurther.java`

thanks

Comment: _"I have to include them all into my main page."_ ? Why? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your main page datatable.xhtml. In datatable.xhtml, I would use JSF's ui:include tag to include each of the dialog boxes code in this page:

```
<ui:include src="dialogAdd.xhtml" /
<ui:include src="dialogEdit.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="dialogFurther.xhtml" />
```

This will allow you to keep the dialog code in separate xhtml pages.

Now for the java part. Let's call your backing bean for the datatable Datatable.java. In Datatable.java, I would do the following:

```
public class Datatable{
    private DialogAdd dialogAdd;
    private DialogEdit dialogEdit;
    private DialogFurther dialogFurther;

    /*Any business logic needed for datatable*/

    /*Getters and setters for the above properties*/
}
```

The objects shown above (DialogAdd, DialogEdit, and DialogFurther) will hold the properties/methods/business logic needed for each of the dialog boxes.

This allows you to modularize both the the xhtml pages and the java.